# Php Js Ajax I need some assistance

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a social dating site and I have my problem in the Add as Buddy Button. When you click it, my site should be sending the uid of the sender (from_uid) and the uid of the receiver (to_uid) to the database. It sends out the from_uid successfully but the to_uid always sends 0.

PHP

```
<div class="member" data-user="<?php echo $member['xmpp_user']; ?>" data-uid="<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenuid" value="<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/wheewhew/user/<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>/photos/<?php echo $member['profile_pic']; ?>" />
  <div class="member_name"><?php echo $member['firstname']." ".$member['lastname']; ?></div>
  <div id="addbutton"><button type="submit" class="add"> Add as Buddy </button></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://wheewhew.com:5280/http-bind';
   var connection   = null;
   var xmpp_user    = "<?php echo $xmpp_user; ?>@wheewhew.com/default";
   var xmpp_pass    = "<?php echo $xmpp_password; ?>";
   var uid          = "<?php echo $uid; ?>";

   $(document).ready(function () {              
     $('#btn-logout').click(logout);
     $('.add').click(addBuddy);
     connectXMPP();
     //updateLastSeen();
   });

</script>
```

jabber.js

```
function addBuddy(){
  var xmpp_user = $(this).parent().attr('data-user')+'@wheewhew.com/default';
  var to_uid = $(this).parent().attr('data-uid');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./ajax/addBuddy",
    data: "from_uid="+uid+"&to_uid="+to_uid,

    success: function(data) {
      var ret = eval('('+data+')');
      if(ret.status == 'success'){
        connection.send($pres({to:xmpp_user,type:'subscribe'}).tree());
      }
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: have u verified that `data-uid="<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>"` displays the correct uid?

Comment: oh, and btw, you should be using `$(this).parent().data('uid')` instead of the `.attr` method, as long as you are using a recent version of jQuery. => http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: yes it displays the correct uid.
whats the difference if i use attr than data?

Comment: other than it being the incorrect vs the correct way to do it? its faster and more accurate.

Comment: ok ill try it. ill be back and tell you what happens :)

Comment: my db is still receiving 0.

Comment: alright, can you do a `console.log(uid)`, or an `alert(uid)` before it gets sent by ajax to make sure the variable itself is not 0?

Comment: wait, do i use uid? im using uid for the users uid and not the receivers uid.

Comment: sorry i meant `to_uid`. my bad.

Comment: the div containing the data-uid is placed in a while function. it gets all the new members and displays it, which will generate alot of data-uid. is it still safe to use it and get the right value?

Comment: oh bloody hell i think i know what it might be. providing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addBuddy` function doesnt have a reference for what `$(this)` is. Try this out:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
     addBuddy($(this));
});
```

And then in your function:

```
function addBuddy($btn){
    var xmpp_user = $btn.parent().attr('data-user')+'@wheewhew.com/default';
    var to_uid = $btn.parent().attr('data-uid');

    // ajaxy stuff
}
```

That should help. At the very least, we can continue the discussion here rather than in the comments for the OP.